# Reading in matrix with specified matrix coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have some matrix data in a text file that looks something like this.

```
1 3 -0.3
1 5 0.5
1 8 -0.7
2 2 -0.6
2 3 -1.0
2 4 0.1
2 8 0.7
3 2 -1.1
2 5 0.8
2 8 0.8
```

For each line the first value is the row, the second the column and the third is the value.

**Question:** How do I best read the data into a matrix?

I tried using numpy and the loadtxt-method, but that obviously reads everything into a matrix.
The actual sample size is also going to be a lot larger than this with missing values as well, so the matrix must be able to contain missing values where coordinates have not been specified.

Any help or hints is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

First read the file (I'm assuming it's named `input.txt`) into a temporary structure (`data`)

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = [[float(n) if i == 2 else int(n)
             for i, n in enumerate(line.split())]
            for line in file.readlines()]
```

then setup the `matrix`

```
matrix = [[None] * max(data[i][1] for i in range(len(data)))
          for _ in range(max(data[i][0] for i in range(len(data))))]
```

and finally fill it where an entry is available

```
for row in data:
    matrix[row[0] - 1][row[1] - 1] = row[2]
```

With your sample data this leads to

```
[[None, None, -0.3, None, 0.5, None, None, -0.7],
 [None, -0.6, -1.0, 0.1, 0.8, None, None, 0.8],
 [None, -1.1, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

I have assumed here that the matrix indices start with `1`. You have to adjust if that's not the case.

PS: You have a double entry in your sample data: `2 8 0.7` and `2 8 0.8`. Is that intentional?

Comment: This is similar to what I ended up doing and it works. And yes the matrix indices start with 1, at least to my understanding. The test data was a quick oversimplification and I ended up with the duplicate on accident, but that won't occur in any actual data. Thanks for your suggestion!